# SwiftUI - only one alert showing in nested if

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I am creating a register view and I have two alerts to show. One is showing if the email or the password don't meet the requirements and the other one is used if the email is already saved in the system. The issue is that the single alert showing up is the one that checks if the email and password meet that set of requirements.

```swift
Button ("Sign Up") {
                    toggle.toggle()
                    
                    if (isValidEmailAddr(strToValidate: userCredentials.email) && isValidPassword(strToVailidate: userCredentials.password)) {
                        if !emailDoesExist(emailToCheck: userCredentials.email) {
                            print("Email and Passowrd are valid")
                            saveJSON(email: userCredentials.email, password: userCredentials.password, nickname: userCredentials.nickname)
                        } else {
                            print("email address already in the system")
                            self.showAlert1.toggle()
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        self.showAlert0.toggle()
                    }
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert1, content: { self.alert1 })
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert0, content: { self.alert0 })
                .font(.title)
                .buttonStyle(.bordered)
                .frame(width:200, height: 100)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly it is only showAlert0 that gets toggled but why it gets toggled (why the validation failed) is dependent on code that is not part of the question or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: showAlert0 shows when needed, but showAlert1 doesn't show up even if emailDoesExist() is true although I get that "email address already in the system" printed in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot attach more than one alert to the same view and now you have two for your button.

There are several ways to approach this to get only one alert and here I use a simple one where I use a second property that holds an error message that can be used in the alert

```
@State private var showAlert = false
@State private var errorMessage = ""
```

```
if (isValidEmailAddr(strToValidate: userCredentials.email) && isValidPassword(strToVailidate: userCredentials.password)) {
    if !emailDoesExist(emailToCheck: userCredentials.email) {
        saveJSON(email: userCredentials.email, password: userCredentials.password, nickname: userCredentials.nickname)
    } else {
        errorMessage = "Mail already exists"
        self.showAlert.toggle()
    }
} else {
    errorMessage = "Mail or password is incorrect"
    self.showAlert.toggle()
}
```

Then you would need to adjust the actual .alert modifier but since I don't know what self.alert0/1 are you need to do that yourself (most likely by keeping only one of them and make use of `errorMessage`).